# Forloops in VUE to create html tags

Tags: javascript, vue.js

This code is for an ejs template in which a json object is passed in. Im trying to create a similar table in VUE.js however v-for in vue seems to only work with li tags. What I want is to be able to create a whole bunch of html with a for loop in VUE just like it is done in the code below in ejs. Any ideas?

```
<%var json2 = json%>
           <%for(var i = 0; i < json2.length; i++) { %>
             <%var obj = json2[i];%>
           <tr>
            <form action="/d" class="f" method="POST" id="target">
             <td>
               <%= obj.pkid%>
               <input type="hidden" name="pkid" value="<%=obj.pkid%>" enctype="application/json" >
             </td>
             <td>
               <%= obj.room%>
             </td>
             <td>
               <%= obj.facility%>
             </td>
             <td>
               <%= obj.city%>
             </td>
             <td>
               <%= obj.state%>
             </td>
             <td>
               <%= obj.address%>
             </td>
             </form>
           </tr>
         <%}%>
```

Comment: v-for works on any element.

Comment: Post whatever you have tried in Vue

Comment: <tr v-for="...">...</tr>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make sure to set json2 as JS array and everything will work finely. Also, do not forget to set `v-model="obj.pkid"` on your input if you want Vue reactivity.

```
<tr v-for="obj in json2">
   <form action="/d" class="f" method="POST" id="target">
      <td>
         {{ obj.pkid }}
         <input type="hidden" name="pkid" v-model="obj.pkid" enctype="application/json">
      </td>
      <td>
         {{ obj.room }}
      </td>
      <td>
         {{ obj.facility }}
      </td>
      <td>
         {{ obj.city }}
      </td>
      <td>
         {{ obj.state }}
      </td>
      <td>
         {{ obj.address }}
      </td>
   </form>
</tr>
```